# looping and fading different text phrases in query

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["Flashing" random text with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059334/flashing-random-text-with-javascript)

I can't figure out how to make this maybe stupid thing.
I have several text phrases that I have to switch between and loop with fading transition.

How can I build this stuff in jQUery?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've answered this exact question myself, I can't seem to find it though.

Comment: Thanks James and Rikudo, but Jasper has learned to fly and to the perfection of what I needed; it is true that when I wrote the question I could be more precise, in fact I was going to change it but I have anticipated, but it seems too much to me score a negative vote on the question. And it's not a duplicate question because array solution is not what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML --

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
    <p>Text 4</p>
</div>
```

CSS --

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#container p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript --

```
function rotate_p() {
    if (p_current == p_count) {
        p_current = 1;
    } else {
        p_current++;
    }
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.find('p').fadeOut();
    $container.find('p:nth-child(' + p_current + ')').fadeIn();
}

var p_count;
var p_current = 0;
var p_interval;
$(document).ready(function () {
    p_count = $('#container').find('p').length;
    p_interval = setInterval(function () {rotate_p();}, 2500);
});
```

This uses an interval to loop through the `<p>` tags within a container `<div>`. The `<p>` tags are set to the same location so the fade in/out will appear on top of each other. On document load the number of `<p>` tags are found and stored in a global variable. The function that runs in the interval hides all the `<p>` tags within the containing `<div>` and then shows the next one in line.

Here is a jsfiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8s7d/

Comment: Thaaankkk youuuu so much Jasper, you were perfect! It's exactly what I needed! I tested it in different browsers and it works perfectly! You're a magician! Thanks!

Comment: jasper I noticed that initially the first paragraph is not displayed and you have to wait the delay time, you can overcome this drawback?

Comment: You can accomplish this by running the `rotate_p()` function on document ready. Just add `rotate_p();` after the `$(document).ready(function () {` line.