# Fading/Flashing Random text with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text, random, fading

Basically a replica of this article only for rails:
["Flashing" random text with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059334/flashing-random-text-with-javascript)
How do I do this?

I haven't tried anything because there are literally none which ask this using Rails, nor do I want to use jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Rails is a server-side application framework. There's no good way to flash random text on the client-side browser using Rails. You will have to use javascript to accomplish this task.

Comment: You never know what Rails can hide within its docs. ooohoohoho spooky... :D That's really shitty, hope something could come along with RAils 4 then :)

Comment: @MFCS I think you're a bit confused about either how Rails works, or how the web works. Rails sends HTML, JSON, JS, etc. to clients. Clients process it, by rendering HTML, executing JS, etc. If you want client behavior, you *have* to put it on the client, by controlling what Rails sends back. Perhaps if you were clearer in your objection(s) to doing it the only way possible we could understand what you're trying to say/do.

Comment: You are right, I am quite confused when it comes to how rails, html, css, javascript and most programming languages work. I do know a little bit though, what classes, controllers, views and the most basic  concepts mean, but I don't really understand the inner workings and neither the skin layer of it. I'm mostly just interested in how to use it, at least now, maybe later I'll spend more time trying to actually understand things which happen :)